# Is there a pythonic way to subtract abstract times?

Tags: python, time

I struggled to come up with the title, but to explain it is probably easier to start with my actual issue.

Concrete problem: I am wrapping a commandline program dealing with audio and need to manipulate song lengths, ex: a 4 minute and 50 second sample `4:50` needs 7 seconds chopped off, to become `4:43`.

The time module doesn't do subtraction and datetime does but gives timedelta, which is the total number of seconds.

Is there a builtin python way or library to do calculations with abstract time, as in not a date?

I can write the code properly formatting the timedelta but this does not feel "batteries included" and really gross using datetime when I'm not actually referencing dates.

All I can find are things that make datetime easier, but not abstract time.  If there is nothing, and this is the best way, that's fine, but I want to make sure it doesn't exist vs not being able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I never realised that this (inability to subtract `datetime.time`). The best I can think of is to subclass `datetime.time` and add the the `__add__` and `__sub__` methods there to return something meaningful.

And I agree that this doesn't feel very "batteries included".